# python db connection

Tags: python

I am having a script which makes a db connection and pereform some select operation.accroding to the fetch data i am calling different functions which also perform db operations.How can i pass db connection to the functions which are being called as i donot want to make new connection

Comment: -1: being more specific about the problem might help

Comment: Not really fair to downvote, users come from all over the world. Sounds as though you need to express your data connection as a variable in your class, then you can pass it in the arguments of the methods you need to call. Not a python man myself, so I'll leav it to someone who knows.

Comment: A DB connection can be passed as an argument to a function.  What specific problem are you having?  Please provide sample code and an error message that shows what is not working.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: no sample code and no error message IS a pretty good reason to downvote, IMO.

Comment: @S.Lott problems occur when you're in a multi-threaded application and your db connection isn't multithread safe

Comment: @kender: Nice hypothesis.  Hopefully, the question will be updated to include facts.

Answer (score 2):

Why to pass connection itself? Maybe build a class that handles all the DB-operation and just pass this class' instance around, calling it's methods to perform selects, inserts and all that DB-specific code?